# Always listening UDP Server

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp

Good afternoon all,

I have been making a UDP server for gathering metrics on my Windows server (SNMP isn't accurate on Windows as it doesn't have 64bit counters). The server runs on the Windows server and the client is running on a Linux monitoring box.

I have set it up running as a service and it is running great except for, every once and a while, the UDP packet is not received from the Linux machine. I am using the following bit of code to receive UDP packets:

```
bytes_received = recvfrom(serverSocket, serverBuf, serverBufLen, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize);
```

The socket is set to timeout every 15 seconds (So any service control requests like stop can be executed). What I am thinking is happening is either:

1. The UDP packet is arriving in between the 15 second timeout and when it starts listening again.
2. The packet is arriving a fraction of a second after another UDP packet has arrived (for a different metric) and it has gone onto starting up a process to send a packet back, and thus it isn't at the recvfrom yet.

(I am basing both of those off my assumption that it is only waiting for a packet when it is at recvfrom).

I could possibly move over to TCP to solve this issue, but since the information is time sensitive, I would prefer to stay with UDP for it's speed.

Is there anyway to queue up incoming packets and have them be processed or would I be best to look at TCP instead?

Comment: That's one of the things about UDP, it's *unreliable* and you can loose packets. Or they can arrive in the wrong order. To help with your first problem use *polling* functions to figure out if there's a packet available to receive before calling `recvfrom`.

Comment: "*The socket is set to timeout every 15 seconds (So any service control requests like stop can be executed)*" - are you handling the socket and SCM on the same thread? If so, move them to separate threads. "*The UDP packet is arriving in between the 15 second timeout and when it starts listening again... and thus it isn't at the recvfrom yet*" - that is perfectly fine. Sockets buffer incoming packets. But, if you overflow the buffer of a UDP socket with too many packets, subsequent packets will be dropped, so you may need to increase the size of the buffer with `setsockopt(SO_RCVBUF)`.

Comment: "*I am basing both of those off my assumption that it is only waiting for a packet when it is at recvfrom*" - that is not true.  See my previous comment. "*Is there anyway to queue up incoming packets*" - it is already doing exactly that.

Comment: I thought the buffer was only used in the recvfrom, no the socket. Looking at my code `serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);` and my bind `int binder = bind(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));`, I don't see where a buffer comes into play.

Comment: Doing a `getsockopt()` shows me that is buffer is currently 131072 in size.

Comment: That is the buffer that comes into play. It belongs to the socket and it is in the kernel, or rather in the UDP layer of the networking stack.

Comment: @chris-p-tech the buffer is in the socket itself. The kernel puts data in the buffer as it arrives on the network. `recvfrom()` simply pulls data from the buffer, waiting if needed for data to arrive. Seems you need to get some good books on network programming.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming up with the idea of transmitting the UDP packet if the first one doesn't get a response after 2 seconds. Works a treat so far.

Edit:

It is asking for code:

```
std::string returnMsg;
returnMsg = "CRITICAL - No packet recieved back.";
int i = 0;

while(returnMsg == "CRITICAL - No packet recieved back.")  {
    if(i == 5) {
        std::cout << "CRITICAL - No packet recieved back." << "\n";
        return 2;
    }
    //std::cout << "Try " << i << "\n";

    // Now lets send the message
    send_message(args[2],message.c_str());

    // Now lets wait for response
    returnMsg = recieve_message();
    
    i++;
}
```

The recieve_message function returns "CRITICAL - No packet recieved back" when the timeout occurs.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Food for thought: what happens if the return message gets lost in transit?

Comment: If it fails to get a response 5 times, it outputs a CRITICAL MESSAGE and returns 2.